# How to resolve problem softdelete restore() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

**i want to restore posts that deleted with softdeletes in laravel:**

**Error:**

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PostController::restore(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

**PostsController:**

```
public function restore($id)
{
    $post= Post::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    $post->restore();
    return redirect()->action('PostController@index');
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('dashboard/posts/restore', 'PostController@restore');
```

**tag in trash.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ action('PostController@restore', ['post' => $post->id]) }}"
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="restore">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that your route accepts a parameter:

```
Route::get('dashboard/posts/restore/{post}', 'PostController@restore');
```